# How to convert quarter which is provided as "FY18 Q1" to produce "2018.4" in C# using REGEX?

Tags: c#, regex

The below code works fine. But, I want to obtain this via `Regex`.

```
private decimal GetQuarter(string quarter)
{
  var unformattedQuarter = "20" + quarter[2] + quarter[3] + "." + quarter[6];
  return Convert.ToDecimal(unformattedQuarter);
}
```

**Input**

FY18 Q4
FY19 Q1
FY19 Q2

**Output**

2018.4
2019.1
2019.2

Comment: Why? The code you have is simple, effective, and fast.

Comment: @IanKemp I want to accomplish this using the `Regex`. Just point of interest.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure this wasn't a "somebody told me to do this simple thing with something new/cool/complicated" question that I'm sure we as all programmers have experienced. :)

Comment: @IanKemp I am learning Regex and never used in the code rather found the alternate and easy way of accomplishing the task. But, it seems for complex things regex is widely used to extract the data or piece of information. Just being curious, wanted to convert the above logic to the regex so that I could gain grip on the Regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pattern

```
FY(\d{2}) Q(\d)
```

And replace matches with

```
20$1.$2
```

**Example**

```
var input = @"FY18 Q4\r\nFY19 Q1\r\nFY19 Q2";
var pattern = @"FY(\d{2}) Q(\d)";
var replacement = "20$1.$2";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement));
```

**Output**

```
2018.4
2019.1
2019.2
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qr3lHy)

---

**Explanation**

[image]

***Note*** : Adding `20` seems a little problematic, and should be used with caution

Comment: Thank you. I had just missed the parenthesis around the text to replace with the $1 and $2.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, you can extract the first and second occurrences of the numbers from the string into a list and then concatenate them:

```
    string n = "FY18 Q1";
    Regex digits = new Regex(@"[\d]+");   
    var list = digits.Matches(n);
    var finalValue = "20" + list [0] + "." + list [1];
```